# Connecting spherical harmonics expansion with 2D Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, spherical-harmonics

A square-integrable function on a sphere $f(\hat n)$ can be expanded as a linear combination of [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Spherical_harmonics_expansion):

$$ f(\hat n) = \sum_{\ell, m} f_\ell^m Y_\ell^m(\hat n),$$

where $\hat n$ is a direction vector and it is usually parameterized by two angles $\theta$ and $\phi$. 
In the limit of small $\theta$, vector $\hat n$ starts to approach the $\hat z$ direction on the sphere and it is often schematically written that

$$ \sum_{\ell, m} f_\ell^m Y_\ell^m(\hat n) 
\to \int \frac{d^2\vec l}{(2\pi)^2}~ \tilde f(\vec l) e^{\vec l\cdot \vec\theta},$$

where the right-hand side it the [2D Fourier transform on a plane](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/image_processing/node6.html). 
I presume that the vector $\vec \theta$ lives now in this 2D plane and is given by the small amplitude $\theta$ and direction determined by $\phi$.

Can somebody show, or point me to, a robust derivation of this limit? 
I was able to find some intuitive explanations of how these two expressions above should correspond to each other in this limit, but this was not quite satisfactory. Is there a solid straightforward way to show this?

Comment: So $\vec l$ is the 2D Fourier variable corresponding to the vector $\vec \theta$ in the 2D plane. The integral measure can be e.g. written as $l dl d\phi_l$ in polar coordinates in the plane. I would also like to know where/how does it all come about... I stumbled on this relation in one of the well-known CMB papers ([link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9609170.pdf), Eq.(32)), but I also thought it is kind of commonly used in physics

Comment: Is it the same function $T$ on both side of eq.33 ?

Comment: Well, not strictly... I think it just means that $T(\vec l)$ on the rhs is supposed to be 2D Fourier transform of the function on the lhs $T(\hat n)$. So maybe it would have been better to use for $T(\vec l)$ on the rhs, somehting like $\tilde T(\vec l)$. However, note that this equation is valid (somehow) only when $\hat n$ is close to $\hat z$ direction.

Comment: Then in your post it is the same you are just considering a function $F(\vec{l})$ whose Fourier transform is $f(\hat{z}+\vec{\theta})$ for $\vec{\theta}$ small, where $\vec{\theta}$ is almost tangent to the sphere so it can be considered as a vector of $R^2$ (the question is if you'd like it to hold for "every" $\vec{\theta}$ in which case you need to extend $f$ to $R^3$ or something)

Comment: Well, I'd like to show that the relation above holds when I take the limit $\hat n$ to $\hat z$, and by taking this limit I have a freedom to define a function $\tilde f(\vec l)$ for which this relation will hold. The expectation is that $\tilde f(\vec l)$ will be somehow related to the $f_l^m$